# drawing a rectangle on an image after identifying the area using ROI (OpenCV)

Tags: opencv, roi

I am trying to use the function ROI in OpenCV to identify a contour, later .. in that ROI I am  identifying a specific color.. so I want to draw rectangle or circle around this shape but in the original image .. the problem that the location I am retrieving is for the ROI and not the whole image .. any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know the offset of the ROI within the original image (say the coordinates of its top-left corner) -- just add these to the coordinates of the location *within* the ROI (ie where the top-left corner of the ROI is (0,0)), and that gives the location in global coordinates.

e.g.:

```
 ______________
|    __        |
|   |  |       |
|   |x_|       |
|______________|
```

Say the outer rectangle is the image, top-left corner (0,0), and the inner square is the ROI, top-left corner (1,3).

The X is the location of the thing you want to outline - it has coordinates (1,0) *with respect to the square*.

Add `(1,0)` (X coordinates with respect to ROI) to the `(1,3)` (ROI coordinates with respect to image) and you'll get `(2,3)`, the coordinates of `X` with respect to the image.